# Code style: passing a reference to subroutine

Tags: perl

Is the subroutine `test1` ugly?/uglier than the others?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ref = { one => 1, two => 2, three => 3 };


sub test1 {
    my ( $ref ) = @_;
    $ref->{three} = 4;
}
test1( $ref );

sub test2 {
    $ref->{three} = 4;
}
test2( $ref );

sub test3 {
    my ( $ref ) = @_;
    $ref->{three} = 4;
    return $ref;
}
$ref = test3( $ref );


say Dumper $ref;
```

Comment: The argument in `test2( $ref );` is ignored.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I had not thought of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some considerations when writing such functions:

- By passing the function all of the variables it needs (`test1`), you don't need to rely on global variables. This makes the function **easier to test**, more **predictable** (no side effects) and **easier to refactor** as you can move it to another module or file easily. If it relied on global variables, it would be broken if the variable is moved or its data structures changed.
- Returning the original reference is not necessary for `test3`, because **the original `$ref` is changed**. Returning is useful if you want to chain function calls.
- Modifying the arguments passed your function directly can be surprising to the function's caller. If you do this, make it clear in the documentation. If you actually want to make a new copy of the object, modify it and return it, use something like [Clone](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Clone). Of course, this can be slow.
- Just in case you are writing object accessors/mutators: please consider using a module such as [Class::Accessor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aAccessor) or the more heavyweight but extensive [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) which can generate such functions for you automatically.